# How to expose IEnumerable of IEnumerable from typed private variable in C# .NET

Tags: c#, collections, ienumerable

This may be a silly question, but...

Is it possible to express:

```
private Dictionary<decimal, List<string>> _internal;
```

as

```
public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<decimal, IEnumerable<string>>> External => something.idontknow...
```

Normally I just use .AsEnumerable() but this is obviously only returns an IEnumerable of the dictionary.

If this is possible, how would I call this public variable by specifying both IEnumerable's filters (.Where() for example) in a single line, so that the filtered result is a result of both?

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Can you show us [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) where we can understand what you are trying to achieve here

Comment: It is, but it seems weird that you would want to do that.

Comment: If I'm understanding the question correctly, you're after something similar to this? [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6LbxFF)

Answer (score 0):

You can't expose the value directly (without some sort of transformation). You would *think* that since  a `Dictionary<K, V>` is an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<K, V>>` and a `List<T>` is an `IEnumerable<T>` that this should be straightforward. Unfortunately it's not as a `KeyValuePair<K, List<V>>` **is not** a `KeyValuePair<K, IEnumerable<V>>` since classes (and structs in this case) are **invariant**.

You have a few options, but they are all going to involve some sort of projection of the source. The first is to simply `Select` a new enumerable, converting the `KeyValuePair<,>` manually:

```cs
private Dictionary<decimal, List<string>> _internal = new();

public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<decimal, IEnumerable<string>>> External
   => _internal.Select(
        c => new KeyValuePair<decimal, IEnumerable<string>>(c.Key, c.Value));
```

The second choice would be to project out to a new Dictionary:

```cs
private Dictionary<decimal, List<string>> _internal = new();

public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<decimal, IEnumerable<string>>> External
    => _internal.ToDictionary(c => c.Key, c => (IEnumerable<string>) c.Value);
```

I wouldn't go that route as it's going to needlessly allocate and have to recompute hashes, etc. But I wanted to call it out anyway.

A third option is a custom iterator *method*:

```cs
private Dictionary<decimal, List<string>> _internal = new();

public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<decimal, IEnumerable<string>>> External() {
    foreach(var (key, value) in _internal) 
        yield return new KeyValuePair<decimal, IEnumerable<string>>(key, value);
}
```

Optionally you can make the tranforming iterator *method* private and then use another property to call it (if you want external usage to be via *property* syntax):

```cs
private Dictionary<decimal, List<string>> _internal = new();

private IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<decimal, IEnumerable<string>>> Iterator() {
    foreach(var (key, value) in _internal) 
        yield return new KeyValuePair<decimal, IEnumerable<string>>(key, value);
}

public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<decimal, IEnumerable<string>>> External => Iterator();
```

See this [SharpLab link](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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) for an example of all four in action.